Singular value decomposition algorithm recommendations for smaller dense matrices
I am looking for recommendations for SVD algorithms for dense matrices. My supervisor specifically requested that I do not use external libraries for this (otherwise I'd likely use LAPACK and call it a day). The matrices are fairly small, usually <50 rows and ~10 columns and this task is only done once. Efficiency is not a huge concern here, but generality and robustness are desirable.
Most resources on SVD tend to steer clear of the algorithms or discuss more specialized algorithms for large systems with restrictions on the matrix shape. I would be very appreciative if some numerical linear algebra folks could point me in the right direction or refer me to specific literature.
Thanks!

numerical recipies

@user619894 do you have a link? The versions I found have some helpful eigenvalue algorithms but nothing explicitly for SVD.

The eigen-decomposition of $\pmatrix{0&A\A^T&0}$ contains the SVD of $A$. Under your stated conditions, just implementing it as such, that is, tridiagonalization via Hessenberg form, then shifted QR algorithm, or multi-shift, or bulge chasing, should work with increasing speed for increasing coding effort. If you use the block structure symbolically and make the algorithm memory and time efficient, you end up with the algorithm of Golub/Kahan. Should be in Golub-van Loan "Matrix computations". // NR is a bit like "popular science", experts are horrified when reading about their specialty.

Thanks @LutzLehmann
I was able to find resources on Golub-Kahan SVD which it seems doable in our scope and would produces a few useful subroutines as a byproduct.
